# How to configure email notification for dependent projects in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have two maven projects, on different Git repositories: core, webapp. Each have a job in Jenkins which pulls the git SCM and runs Maven build.

If someone committed bad code to webapp, then Jenkins will send him an email that the build failed. Same goes for core.

**The problematic scenario**

John commits bad code to core, but it doesn't break core unit tests / compilation, but breaks webapp compilation. In this case, Jenkins does *not* sends an email, since no commit was made in webapp. Webapp job was being triggered since core was changed and it triggered its build.
Jenkins output was:

```
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
```

How do I configure jenkins to pull the list of committers in the jobs that triggered this job being built and send them the email as well that the build failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [**Blame Upstream Committers** Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Blame+Upstream+Committers+Plugin) - 
the page there describes how to use *fingerprints* to identify the committers.

Comment: In theory it should work, so great answer! I encountered a bug, and opened it in JIRA: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14868